# RESTful Web Service eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, jersey

I followed a very nice tutorial and it works smoothly for the `GET` http method, but for some reason when I try to access the `POST` or `PUT` methods the server returns:

> HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

So this is what I did in the tutorial,

- I created a new dynamic web project
- I imported the jersey RESTful implementation
- I created a new java class and set some jersey annotations
- I edited the web.xml file for it to create a servlet on start up with some Jersey set up and point it to my Java class mapping it.

That's it, I ran the app on a tomcat 6 app server.

So when I follow the path of my class and I hence a `@GET` method it works smoothly but when i try to replace the `@GET` annotation with `@POST` it return the error above.

The web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>RESTfulTest</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>NAME</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>com.RESTful.Test</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>NAME</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

My Java class with the jersey annotations:

```
package com.RESTful.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/resttest")
public class Test {

    //this WORKS!
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getTestString()
    {
        return "Hello this is a test post";
    }
    //this returns the error
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getTestString2()
    {
        return "Hello this is a test post";
    }
    //this returns the error
    @PUT
    @Path("{param1}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getTstWithInput(@PathParam("/param1") 
            String param)
    {
        return "hello "+param;
    }
    //this returns the error
    @PUT
    @Path(value="/putTest")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getTstWithInput2(@PathParam("/param1") 
            String param)
    {
        return "hello "+param;
    }
}
```

Please note that I have tried documenting all but the method I'm testing with the same results. I know I can't run some of them at the same time, they are all just tests.

I'm calling the REST resources from URL:

- "http://localhost/RESTfulTest/rest/resttest/"
- "http://localhost/RESTfulTest/rest/resttest/myname"
- "http://localhost/RESTfulTest/rest/resttest/putTest"

Comment: how are you calling your rest resources?

Comment: please tell the exact detail as just pasting http://localhost/RESTfulTest/rest/resttest/putTest in a browser will make a GET request which will return 405 error. A common tool is curl .. "curl -XPUT http://localhost/RESTfulTest/rest/resttest/putTest"

Comment: Thank you i thought the browsers send post as well! thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
return Response.status(200).entity("Sample Response").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
```

More Details :
 http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the rest resources are called properly. Curl can be a hepful tool for testing

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost/RESTfulTest/rest/resttest/putTest
```